# How to stop current file upload in submit sftp?

Tags: ftp, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I was uploading files through sublime sftp. But i don't find any source through which we can stop the current file upload in sublime sftp except closing the whole program. So if any one knows about this problem please tell me how to stop current file upload in submit sftp?

Comment: Please reply on my below answer. Did you try tips from my answer ? *If it unhelpful I'll just remove it*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+(<kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>) - [Stop the current SFTP/FTP server activity (connection, upload or download)](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/usage#command-Cancel).

Answer (score 7):

It's useful to use `ctrl + \`,get it from here: https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2010-July/028866.html